# Execute queries stored in columns of a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor, relational-database

I have a table with 2 columns `QueryName` and `Query`. I am trying the execute the queries stored in the `Query` column of the table.

I want to display anything that has more than record count of zero, we need to print to output with `queryname` and `count`. I am using the following cursor, I was able to display `rowcount` but anyone please suggest me how to display the `QueryName`:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE Cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    (SELECT Query 
     FROM VWLetterTYB )

OPEN Cur

FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Sql

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    --Exec sp_executesql @Sql
    EXEC ('SELECT COUNT(*) AS Rowcounts FROM (' + @sql + ') AS t HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 ')

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Sql 
END

CLOSE Cur
DEALLOCATE Cur;
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: is Query just a table name? if so just add it to the select as a string literal

Comment: What if a query uses a CTE?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE Cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    (SELECT Query 
     FROM VWLetterTYB )

OPEN Cur

FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Sql

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    --Exec sp_executesql @Sql
    EXEC ('SELECT [sql] = ''' + @Sql + ''', COUNT(*) AS Rowcounts FROM (' + @sql + ') AS t HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 ')

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Sql 
END

CLOSE Cur
DEALLOCATE Cur;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have two fields in the table but you only managed to get one using the cursor. In that case, the solution is easy, you can fetch more than one value with a cursor (each one to a different variable), then just put that value in the dynamic `SELECT`:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @QueryName NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE Cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    (SELECT Query, QueryName 
     FROM VWLetterTYB )

OPEN Cur

-- variables are filled in the order used in the SELECT (first column to first variable,
-- second column to second variable, etc.)
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Sql, @QueryName 

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    -- when using single quotes inside a string you have to double it
    EXEC ('SELECT '''+ @QueryName+''' AS QueryName, COUNT(*) AS Rowcounts FROM (' + @sql + ') AS t HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 ')

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Sql, @QueryName
END

CLOSE Cur
DEALLOCATE Cur;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but a further refinement of the question.  The examples here are using the stored SQL as a standalone command.  Can a snippet of SQL stored in a table's column be used as an item in a SELECT list?

I have a situation where I have a table of code/name lookup pairs. Most codes lead to a single name.  But something logic needs to be applied to determine the name.  I would like to have this seamless in my master SQL statement.  I have to apply this logic from the same lookup table in many scripts.  I don't want to have to embed complex logic in each script or maintain a convoluted stored procedure.